# Redirect users away from Admin breaks ajax

Tags: wp-admin, ajax, wp-redirect

Tried to make a simple redirect for some users I don't want to access the wp-admin/, so I did this code:

```
function no_admin_access() {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'delete_posts' ) ) {
        wp_redirect( site_url( '/' ) ); exit;
    }
}
add_action('admin_init', 'no_admin_access');
```

But when I then try to make a ajax request with those users, the that is also redirected so I never get to admin-ajax.php

Anybody who has a good work around for this ?

Thanks.

AJAX Code

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: MyAjax.ajaxurl,
    data: {
        action: 'mux_ajax_delete_pix',
        pid: $this.attr('data-id')
    },
    success: function(){
        $this.parent().fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Comment: Please show your _complete_ AJAX related code - I'm pretty sure that you're simply locking yourself out. (Happens to the best).

Comment: I have added the Ajax code, but Bainternet answer below worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can and a check for the `DOING_AJAX` constant which is defined on an Ajax in your conditional check:

```
function no_admin_access()
{
    if (
        // Don't do this for AJAX calls
        ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) 
        // Capability check
        && ! current_user_can( 'delete_posts' ) 
        )
    {
        // Redirect to home/front page
        wp_redirect( site_url( '/' ) );
        // Never ever(!) forget to exit(); or die(); after a redirect
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'no_admin_access' );
```

Comment: Works great on the backend, but doesn't work for front end posting. Authors can't upload images with this solution on the front end. Still can't find a way around that...

Answer (score 0):

i'm using below function and it is working fine for me

`function remove_admin_access_for_non_editor() {
if ( is_admin() && ! current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) && ! ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) ) {
    wp_redirect( home_url() );
    exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'remove_admin_access_for_non_editor' );`